# ApplicationView does not contain a definition for GetForCurrentView?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, orientation

I'm currently following a tutorial from the MSDN which isn't very clear on somethings the issue that i am having is that the method that they are suggesting that i use is apparently not available to that class

Here is the link to the tutorial : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn495655.aspx

Here is the code that i am using

In my App.Xaml.cs not my Main page i have an event handler

```
   public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Window.Current.SizeChanged += Current_SizeChanged;
            this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
        }
```

Underneath this the stub method

```
 void Current_SizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the new view state but its not allowing me to use getforcurrent state
        // almost like it doesn't exist
        string CurrentViewState = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Orientation.ToString();

        // Trigger the Visual State Manager
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, CurrentViewState, true);

    }
```

If anyone else has followed this tutorial can they tell me what is going wrong ?

- Have i put the code in the wrong page
- Am i missing a library

I am following this microsoft tutorial word for word and it giving me the error which is the title of my post i have done research and i am using the latest version of visual studio and it's still not letting me use this method because it do not exist apparently

Comment: The tutorial you're following is for Windows 8 modern applications. You tagged this question as Windows Phone 8 related. So which one are you developing for?

Comment: I seem to have made a mistake i am currently developing a blank app page (tablet) shown in the tutorials

Answer (score 3):

Try using Windows.UI.ViewManagement; at the top of the program.

Comment: This should be the answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum supported version of this API is Windows 8.1. So you can't use it with the Windows 8 API.
[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.getforcurrentview)

Comment: So is there not not anyway to get the equivalent for windows 8